# Como redirecionar caso usuário seja não autorizado

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Estou utilizando em minha aplicação, `roles` e estou tentando caso, o usuário não esteja autorizado, seja redirecionado para uma pagina de erro.

Estou utilizando `ASP.NET MVC com Identity`, em pesquisa na internet e aqui no StackOverFlow, achei algumas respostas, porém nenhuma delas funcionou:

[ASP.NET - Redirect to Error Page if Roles Authorization Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447705/asp-net-redirect-to-error-page-if-roles-authorization-fails)

Neste caso, criei uma classe, e sub-escrevi o método `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`, ficando assim:

```
public class PermissoesFiltro : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // The user is not authenticated
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else if (!this.Roles.Split(',').Any(filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole))
        {
            // The user is not in any of the listed roles => 
            // show the unauthorized view
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Page_403.cshtml"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Neste outro exemplo: [Autenticação e Permissões de usuários em ASP.NET MVC 4](http://devbrasil.net/profiles/blog/show?id=2307362%3ABlogPost%3A158798&commentId=2307362%3AComment%3A266380&xg_source=activity)

Tambem criei uma classe, e sub-escrevi o método `OnAuthorization`, ficando assim:

```
public class PermissoesFiltro : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if(filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Views/Shared/Page_403.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

Mas nenhum dos dois funcina, quando tento acessar uma pagina que não esta autorizada, sou redirecionado para a tela de login.

Meu controller:

- Index - somente usuarios autenticados;
- About - usuarios atenticados que pertencem a regra "TESTE";
- Contact - Todos.

  ```
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
      [Authorize]
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
          return View();
      }

      [Authorize(Roles = "TESTE")]
      public ActionResult About()
      {
          ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

          return View();
      }


      public ActionResult Contact()
      {
          ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

          return View();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Como está a assinatura do controller? Coloca o código para a gente ver, por favor?

Comment: Fiz uma revisão obrigado.

Comment: Porque não está usando   [PermissoesFiltro] em vez de   [Authorize]. Você criou o atributo mas não está usando

Comment: @Murilo não entendi, então eu queria utilizar as `roles` porem direcionando para uma pagina especifica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize:

```
[PermissoesFiltro(Roles = "TESTE")]
public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

    return View();
}
```

Você criou a classe `PermissoesFiltro` que herda de `AuthorizeAttribute` mas não disse ao controller pra usar ela.

Da forma atual ele irá usar o esquema de autenticação padrão, não o personalizado que você definiu.

Answer (score 1):

Para demonstrar o que o @Murilo falou no comentário:

```
 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

O `[Authorize]` redireciona por padrão para o login.

Muda ele para usar o `[PermissoesFiltro]`

```
[PermissoesFiltro]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```